# "Tra" e "dopo" possono avere valore di complemento di luogo?

Tags: grammar

"Tra" e "dopo" possono avere valore di complemento di luogo?

Riporto le frasi su cui sono dubbioso:

> "Abito un km dopo il punto x"
>
> "Mi trovo tra un km"

Ho dei dubbi a riguardo.

A me la preposizione "tra" non sembra affatto dare valore di luogo, ma piuttosto SOLO temporale.
La seconda frase per me non è corretta e non mi suona e dubito possa rispondere alla domanda: in che luogo?

Comment: Non puoi essere in due posti. Mi trovo tra un chilometro non è corretto.

Answer (score 2):

La prima frase è corretta: in questo caso si tratta di un complemento di stato in luogo che specifica il contesto spaziale in cui si svolge l'azione, come puoi anche vedere in [questa interessante tabella sull'analisi logica](http://facolta.unica.it/studiumanistici/files/2015/09/Corso-di-riallineamento-Lingua-italiana-Profssa-Cossu-Tabella-complementi.pdf).
In questo caso *dopo* di significa a partire da, nelle vicinanze di un luogo. Il verbo abitare indica permanenza o stato.

La seconda frase invece non è totalmente scorretta anche se il *tra* si usa solitamente nel caso dello stato in luogo se si dice:

> Mi trovo tra Genova e Savona

oppure nel caso di moto per luogo dicendo:

> Sono passato tra i campi di grano

Come suggerito da @DaG:

> Anche se il secondo esempio dell'OP suona strano, concordo con @egreg
>   che la forma “tra” + indicazione di distanza possa costituire un
>   lecito complemento di luogo, anche in frasi come
>
> > “Ci siamo quasi: tra un chilometro siamo arrivati”
>
> oppure
>
> > “Tra un chilometro cominciano le buche”,
>
> colloquiali ma realistiche.  E sforzandoci un po', potremmo anche
>   costruire un contesto in cui quella frase ha senso: qualcosa come
>
> > “Ti sei fermato troppo presto, non mi trovo dove stai tu, mi trovo tra
> >     un km.”
>
> Ma in effetti forse viene più naturale dire “Mi trovo un chilometro
>   più avanti” o in altri modi.

Comment: Se stessi dando indicazioni al telefono, potrei dire al mio interlocutore “prosegui diritto, mi trovi fra (tra) cinquecento metri”.

Comment: È vero, ma allora sarebbe l'equivalente di _Mi trovi tra un km_, sottintendendo rispetto al punto in cui sei tu ora. Con _Mi trovo_ la frase non ha senso e non è corretta..

Comment: Anche se il secondo esempio dell'OP suona strano, concordo con @egreg che la forma “tra” + indicazione di distanza possa costituire un lecito complemento di luogo, anche in frasi come “Ci siamo quasi: tra un chilometro siamo arrivati” oppure “Tra un chilometro cominciano le buche”, colloquiali ma realistiche.

Comment: E sforzandoci un po', potremmo anche costruire un contesto in cui quella frase ha senso: qualcosa come “Ti sei fermato troppo presto, non mi trovo dove stai tu, mi trovo tra un km”. Ma in effetti forse viene più naturale dire “Mi trovo un chilometro più avanti” o in altri modi.

Comment: @DaG Condivido il tuo punto di vista, anche se effettivamente a me in prima istanza non suonava corretta. Direi che potrei modificare la risposta includendo le tue utili osservazioni.